# Xamarin Forms generate XAML for a view

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to generate XAML for a Xamarin forms view created in code behind (basically opposite of `XamlLoader.Load`). I tried using `XamlWriter.Save` but it only writes the parent element and none of the child elements.

Comment: I don't think this is supported in the Xamarin XAML implementation

Comment: @Jason there has to be some way to do this. I tried writing the XAML out myself but now I am getting ton's of garbage with it as well. Is there a internal class that does that in Xamarin framework?

Comment: Why does there have to be a way to do it?  There is no reason Xamarin's tooling can't just consume XAML without being able to write it.  What's the use case for needing to generate XAML from code?  If you're comfortable writing your UI in code that's perfectly acceptable.  XAML is just an alternate way to do it.

Comment: @Jason I want server to generate dynamic page and send XAML to client app which client app can load as a content page.

Comment: You might want to bring this up on the Xamarin forums, but I'm reasonably confident that this won't work.

Comment: @Jason Why wouldn't XamlWriter work for this?

Comment: I was actually talking about dynamically downloading a XAML page - on iOS at least that would be forbidden.  I also don't know that XamlWriter works with Xamarin Form's flavor of XAML